# Non English characters in HTML getting garbled when file is viewed with tomcat

Tags: html, tomcat, web-applications, struts-1

I have a web app running on Tomcat and in its working directory, I have some HTML files that contain text with some non-English characters. From the webapp there is a link to view this file and when the file is viewed from this link, **the contents of the file are garbled.** 
i.e., the characters OpenPGM 組播數據傳輸 get displayed as OpenPGM çµ„æ’­æ•¸æ“šå‚³è¼¸

Here are screenshots for reference:
[When accessed with tomcat URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSji0.png)

[When accessed by opening the file with browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SZ8X.png)

But when I open the file with the browser, the characters are displayed correctly.

This behavior has led me to believe that the issue is with the way tomcat is displaying the data.

Till now I have checked the file encoding set in JAVA_OPTS (which is UTF-8), I even checked the tomcat server.xml for URIEncoding param and it is also UTF 8 (Even though it is for URIs and not the file content).

Any help on this will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer. You can set the character encoding of the response returned by tomcat. So in my case, from web.xml I checked which filter which my request was entering and at the point where the response was being returned, I added

> response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

This resulted in the headers of response (to the request made by tomcat for the file) containing the charset info which rendered the page correctly.

Hope this helps someone!